# Fastest way to compare two same-length strings

Tags: c, string, performance, compare

Strings are fixed length 8, contain alphanumeric characters and right-padded with spaces.

I.e,

```
"STRING1 "
"STR2    "
"S       "
```

etc..

I was thinking `memcmp` might be the fastest here?

Comment: Profile profile profile... and if string comparison isn't the bottleneck in your application (i.e. if you aren't comparing thousands of strings in a tight loop), don't over-optimize aimlessly.

Comment: `std::pair<const char*, const char*> p = std::mismatch(str1, str1 + 8, str2); if (p.first == str1 + 8) { ... }`. For char*, the c++ library **should** call memcmp.

Comment: There's a scientific reason for @Kerrek's suggestion: [Amdahl's law](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/CACHE/amdahl.html). In short: If you need to optimize, find the most frequent case first, and optimize it then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you ensure that the strings are aligned on an 8-byte boundary via compiler-specific attributes, you can do:

```
uint64_t a = *((uint64_t *) "STRING1 ");
uint64_t b = *((uint64_t *) "STR2    ");
```

Then `a == b` should yield to a single 64-bit instruction.

Or, if they are just constant immutable strings (stored in a read-only area of the process), you can go on with comparing the `const char *` pointers themselves. It's still a reliable test since a string literal that appears twice in the current translation unit should refer to the same memory:

```
/* fails because the two strings are stored at different locations */
"STRING1 " == "STR2    "
/* should succeed, even the silliest compiler should merge both literals */
"STRING1 " == "STRING1 "
```

Comment: Could be an endian issue if you save these values over a network, then load them on another platform. There's also the chance that the string won't be aligned properly for the access - many platforms won't like to access uint64_t except aligned to an 8-byte boundary, but there's no such constraint for char arrays. +1 for at least the basis of a good idea, though - it should be easy enough to work around any problems.

Comment: I don't think that this is such a brilliant idea. On a decent platform `memcmp` with a constant size as parameter should amount to something similar without obfuscating the code for a dubious optimization.

Comment: @JensGustedt: if you consider that an obfuscation, then don't take a look at the `ngx_strXXcmp` macros [here](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/http/ngx_http_parse.c) :-)

Comment: The downside is that this is technically undefined behaviour... unless you find a compiler extension that guarantees this will work.

Comment: @KerrekSB: since `malloc` guarantees an alignment to at least 8 bytes, this trick can be safe and applicable in practice even if you don't resort to compiler extensions.

Comment: @Blagovest - I've been trying to think of a real-world case where your claim would be wrong, and I can't. There are certainly platforms where the 8 byte alignment won't be guaranteed - e.g. for 32-bit platforms. But if they support 64-bit integers at all, they will "emulate" them using two 32-bit integer building blocks, so only four-byte alignment will be needed anyway. The only exception I can think of is something like using MMX instructions in 32-bit code - and if your compiler is doing that, you're probably aware and in control of it.

Comment: this is not legal C as it violates the aliasing rules in addition to possible implementation-defined alignment requirements; a portable solution would be to `memcpy()` the strings into `uint64_t` variables first (which will likely be slower than just using `memcmp()`) or to wrap the strings in unions, which will take care of both aliasing and alignment; your second approach is also not guaranteed to work, and there's actually at leat one (non-optimizing) compiler which will not re-use identical string literals: TinyCC

Comment: @Christoph - there's a big difference between "illegal" and "undefined behaviour". Though I should point out - some compilers, such as GCC, are exploiting standards-undefined behaviour for optimisation - as a cynic, I see this as why-work-slowly-when-you-can-crash-far-quicker. There are special rules for casting to/from `void*`, so that intermediate step may help, though I'd have to revisit my old notes to be sure. The GCC manual also recommends a union-based punning idiom, but this is only guaranteed to work on GCC - it's standards-undefined behaviour again.

Comment: @Christoph - the reason I think this optimisation issue is bad - either programmers are allowed to exploit standards-undefined behaviour for particular compilers and platforms or not. If they are, having semantics that are badly defined and change unexpectedly so the code breaks isn't very helpful. A particular compiler should define well-defined semantics even if the standard doesn't. If programmers aren't allowed to exploit standards-undefined behaviour, then there should be no such behaviour in the code for the compiler to exploit, so why bother with the optimisations?

Comment: @Steve314: type-punning through unions is legal in ISO-C99 - a footnote which states that explicitly was added with TC3; if you don't like 'illegal' as a synonym for 'invokes undefined behaviour', use 'non-portable', 'code that will break if you squint wrongly at your compiler flags' or 'code that can make demons fly out of your nose on confirming implementations'

Comment: @Steve314:re 2nd comment: that's what implementation-defined behaviour is for; undefined behaviour is for cases where the compiler is free to do whatever it wants, and especially differents things on different optimization levels; the programmer isn't supposed to exploit undefined behaviour, but the compiler writer is!

Comment: @Cristoph - C and C++ leave a lot standards-undefined to allow compilers to do the platform-specific thing - precisely so that programmers working on those platforms can use that platform-specific behaviour. If there's no defined semantics - whether standards-defined or platform-defined - then code that tries to invoke those undefined semantics is an error and should be treated as such. For a compiler to have optimisations for something that can only be an error is insane - wasted time, effort and complexity.

Comment: @Christop - the idea that standards-undefined behaviour is there to allow different behaviour for different optimisations on the same compiler and platform is very recent - *much* more recent than the standards-undefined behaviour itself. And I'll never agree that changing semantics of real-world code depending on optimisation level is a good idea. Either the semantics are fixed, or invoking the undefined semantics is an error and optimising the broken code is pointless (or worse, an excellent way to make it even harder to debug).

Comment: @Steve314: platform-specific things that you're supposed to use are implementation-defined, not undefined; also, the compiler doesn't optimize undefined behaviour - rather, the behaviour of undefined code is a by-product of the optimizations performed on defined code; sure, implementation-defined is one possible form for a specific instance of undefined behaviour, but code that relies on that is by definition non-portable, possibly not even between different compilers on the same architecture; also, different behaviour of undefined code depending on compiler flags is not a recent thing

Comment: @Christoph - the reason I kept using "standards-undefined" was because I meant things that are undefined in the standard. Not all code is meant to be portable - embedded systems tend to use heavily non-portable code, and standards-undefinedness is often a concession to embedded systems. Different behaviour of undefined code depending on flags isn't recent - but intentionally different semantics for standards-undefined-yet-still-quite-commonly-used code constructs purely to run things faster (by not doing what they were intended to do) is a *very* recent idea.

Comment: @Christoph - I particular like this blog post: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 - although in my current mood I can't resist quoting "One suspects that the C standard body simply got used to throwing behaviors into the “undefined” bucket and got a little carried away. Actually, since the C99 standard lists 191 different kinds of undefined behavior, it’s fair to say they got a lot carried away.", on the whole it's more balanced. Because I'm arguing against you and focussed on one special-case point, it's far more balanced that I am right now.

Comment: @Christoph - example (from that blog) - signed integer overflow invokes standards-undefined behaviour. Semantics on most systems were 2s-complement anyway until very recently, when e.g. GCC "got a little bit smarter". This seems dubious to people who got used to 2s-complement and who know their hardware still works that way, but assuming the speed improvements help code that *doesn't* overflow, but where the compiler can't prove that - a lot of code, as it happens - my earlier crash-quickly argument doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4):

If the strings have fixed equal length, then `memcmp` is a good approach.